# HTML NewLine Issue

Tags: html, vba

[image: Screeshot]I have the below code in VBA which includes newline (vbnewline / vbcrlf) . Then I am calling the variable "Clientname" in .htmlbody. But it is putting the entire string in one line eliminating the newline

```
  'Variable "un" will be assigned a value using a "For loop" above this code

 Reading Text file: 

Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\test.txt")
TxtPro = oFS.ReadAll

 If Not (InStr(ClientName, un)) > 0 Then
   ClientName = ClientName & vbNewLine & un
 End If

with objmail
.bodyformat = olformatHTML
.htmlbody = "<HTML><BODY> " & clientname  & _
     "<Br> Your File is given below <br> " & txtpro & "</body></html>"
end with
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTML` doesn't understand/parse line feeds in the same way as VBA does. Use `<BR>` tag for HTML.

Change this line `ClientName = ClientName & vbNewLine & un` to `ClientName = ClientName & "<BR>" & un`

Edit as per your updated question:

```
Sub test()

    Dim oFSO         As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim oFS          As Object

    Dim txtPro      As String
    Dim strHTML     As String
    Dim clientName  As String

    Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\test.txt")
    txtPro = oFS.ReadAll()

    '/ This will replace linefeeds with <BR> to render line breaks in HTML
    txtPro = Replace(txtPro, vbCrLf, "<BR>")

    strHTML = "<HTML><BODY> " & clientName & _
     "<Br> Your File is given below <br> " & txtPro & "</body></html>"

End Sub
```

Comment: Just like that ehh...    It worked. In the same breath, can you please also let me know why is it messing up the format that it already has. It reads a text file and assigns it into a variable txtpro. But when I recall it in the .htmlbody , the format is all messed up. Changed the original coding above.

Comment: didn't get you. Can you show the image of the format you are expecting vs the format you are getting. Also the TxtPro variable is never used after assignment.

Comment: A screenshot of both correct and incorrect formats are updated. Also, modified the coding to call txtpro variable

Comment: its because of the same reason, `oFS.ReadAll` gets the text with standard line feeds but HTML requires <BR> in place of that. Try to replace that in the string.  Let me know, if you need me help with the code.

Comment: I am not sure how that can be done, since it is reading the file as a single entity.

Comment: See the edit in the answer. Hope this will resolve your issue :)

Comment: That's Awesome... Working like a char... Thank You So Much!